# How to make sure ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay keeps on executing even if there are any exceptions

Tags: java, java-6

Assume I have an asynchronous disk clean-up task. I want the task to be executed once every 2 minutes.

However if one of the execution fails or throws an IOException I do not want subsequent executions to stop.

Is there a non-messy way to do this in Java 6?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a simple try/catch/finally?

Comment: Doesn't it work that way already?

Comment: It isn't. If there is an exception further executions will be supressed.